# Why am I getting this syntax error: keyword can't be an expression

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def multiply():
    number_1 = int (input ("Please insert the first number for multiplication:"))
    number_2 = int (input ("Please insert the second number for multiplication:"))
    result = str (number_1*number_2)
    return print (number_1*number_2=result)
multiply()
```

I am getting the Following error when trying to execute the following function.

```
    return print (number_1*number_2=result)               
                 ^
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

Comment: You don't need to return a print statement.  Choose one or the other

Comment: Because you're literally doing `return print ()`. Your code is a mess. Please read a basic python tutorial and try to understand what you're doing with it...

Comment: If you want to print text, it needs to be in a string. You can leave off the quotes if you want to print values of variables or expressions.

Comment: @Nepho It's not the `return print`, it's the `a*b=c` inside a `print()`.

Comment: @glibdud I didn't even get past the `return print`, my mistake

Comment: @Nepho: in Python 3, `print()` is a function. It always returns `None`, but you *can* return that result. `return print(...)` is perfectly valid syntax in Python 3. In Python 2, unless you use a `__future__` import statement, `print` is a *statement* and can't be part of a `return` statement. You'd get a different syntax error however.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm well aware of that, but given the code, it was pretty evident that this was just the product of lacking knowledge regarding python. Not some aware coding decision.

Comment: @Nepho: your (eroneously) upvoted comment above suggested otherwise. The error is not because they are doing `return print ()`.

Comment: I might have jumped on the gun assuming that it was python2, my mistake.

Comment: @Nepho Im a doing the basic python tutorial for 2 months ...still learning, sorry for the messy code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are defining a keyword argument by using `=`:

```
...(number_1*number_2=result)
                     ^
```

That makes everything *before* the `=` a Python expression, namely `number_1 * number_2`. Python doesn't allow this.

If you wanted to print out a nicely formatted expression, you'll have to use separate string arguments:

```
print(number_1, '*', number_2, '=', result)
```

Python writes out separate arguments with a space to separate them (but you can use `sep='...'` to set a different string to separate them, including the *empty* string to have no separation at all).

Note that you don't actually have to convert `result` to a string here, the `print()` function converts all arguments to strings before writing them to the console.

You could also learn about [Python string formatting](https://pyformat.info/), which gives you a bit more control over the whitespace handling, as well as alignment end value formatting, for example.

The following would print out your numbers and the result as part of a format string with the same amount of spaces:

```
print('{} * {} = {}'.format(number_1, number_2, result))
```

Each `{}` placeholder is then filled with the next argument you passed into the [`str.format()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). You can remove the spaces here too if you wanted to.

Last, but not least, the `print()` function always returns `None`. You don't have to return that from your function, remove the `return`. Your actual use of the `multiply` function doesn't use the returned value anyway:

```
def multiply():
    number_1 = int(input("Please insert the first number for multiplication:"))
    number_2 = int(input("Please insert the second number for multiplication:"))
    result = number_1 * number_2
    print(number_1, '*', number_2, '=', result)

multiply()
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why am I getting this syntax error: keyword can't be an expression

Because what you write in parentheses after a function name (including `print` in python3) are arguments of the function. Any argument written in the form `keyword=value` is a [keyword argument](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments). You cannot use an expression (here a product) as a keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want output like

```
number_1*number2 = 6
```

The first part of this is some fixed text you want printed. Thus you need to put in in a string and print that. You can print multiple things like `print(a, b)`. This should be enough for you to figure out

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues:

You are writing an expression inside a print statement. Instead you want to make a formatted string and substitute the values into the string:

`print("%d*%d=%s" % (number_1, number_2, result))`

Secondly, you don't need to return it.